# Plot a histogram sort by values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have a Pandas dataframe as following:

```
              number
Art           10000
Comics        235
Crafts        293
Dance         824
```

How can I plot a histogram that sort by values?

Demonstration:

```
*
* *
* *
* *
* *
* * * *
* * * *
-------------
x labels = Art/ Dance/ Crafts/ Comics
```

I have tried `pandas.DataFrame.hist`, but not sure how to select proper arguments.

Comment: What you trying to plot is not a histogram by definition. It's a simple bar chart.

Comment: you should use `pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar` : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html`

Answer (score 1):

You can just sort your dataframe first and then create the plot using your dataframes `plot` method

Test data (I set `category` as the index as thats what it looks like you have for your actual data):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['Art', 'Comics', 'Crafts', 'Dance'],
                   'number': [10000, 235, 293, 824]})
df.set_index('category', inplace=True)

          number
category        
Art        10000
Comics       235
Crafts       293
Dance        824
```

Then sort by `number` using `df.sort_values()` and call `df.plot()`:

```
df.sort_values('number', inplace=True)

df.plot(y='number', kind='bar', legend=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That works. But I am just wondering why you're plot has multiple colors by default while my plot has only single color?

Comment: hmm not sure why default colour behaviour is different, I think it might be version specific (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967310/change-colours-of-pandas-bar-chart)

Comment: If you want, you can pass in a list of colours to manually control the colour for each bar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897261/pandas-plot-dataframe-barplot-with-colors-by-category

Comment: the chart in the answer is a bar chart and it is not necessarily a histogram.