# Add legend to barplot composed of numerous catogies

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend

This question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897261/pandas-plot-dataframe-barplot-with-colors-by-category). After I plot the barplot with different colors, I would like to add a corresponding legend but I cannot figure out how. Is it even possible?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':np.arange(0,10,1),'values':np.random.randint(0,100,10),
'group':list('aaabbbcccd')})

colors = {'a':'red','b':'gold','c':'lightblue','d':'cyan'}
df['values'].plot(kind='bar', color=[colors[i] for i in df['group']])
```

It doesn't seem possible in the present solution but I tried iterating over the groups(using groupby) and plotting them onto the same axis but the plots don't come out correctly. Any alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.pivot` to get things into the right structure and then just use `.plot`:

```
df.pivot("index", "group")["values"].plot(kind="bar")
```

[image]